# Ecommerce/Shopping Cart (and checkout process) : use Relational or NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, oracle, cassandra, nosql, rdbms

For the use-case of Shopping cart (and checkout process) for E-commerce web application, what is better to use a Relational **DB** (RDBMS) or **NoSQL DB** as MongoDB/Cassandra/others ?

For the catalog perspective, `NoSQL` makes ideal use-case with flexible schema, horizontal scaling of data/nodes.

What are the pros/cons of each approach for Shopping Cart use-case?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many differences between SQL and noSQL databases. Those differences are what gives each storage type its pros and cons on different situations.

Since both database types would work in the end, it all really depends on the context or on your implementation.

In this specific case (shopping cart), the pros and cons are probably all related to the **consistency** of your data and **scalability**.

noSQL databses are better (pros) suited for more "dynamic" applications (data analysis, IoT, multimedia, etc.). Such applications use data that usually doesn't have a rigid structure and comes in very large volumes. This means that there's no need to develop a complex database model and it's cheaper to store large amounts of data throughout separate "nodes". This also makes noSQL databases easier to expand and scale. The main problem (cons) is the lack of structure. This will make it harder for you to run analysis and to keep track of every detail of the database.

Meanwhile, SQL databases are useful (pros) when your data is well-structured and mostly consistent. As you know, SQL stores data in columns and rows, this gives SQL an advantage if you want to generate detailed statistics of your data and also if you want to keep an organized record of everything that happens in your app. The main downside (cons) is that the design of an SQL database takes more time and also it's probably more expensive (scalability and physical storage require more hardware) to maintain a SQL database.

Performancewise, I would argue that in this usecase there wouldn't be any major difference.

If you think about all of what i just wrote, I would say that **in the context of a shopping cart, the SQL model is the way to go**. A shopping cart won't require lots of upgrades and changes (scalability), its data is always structured (name of item, price, etc.) and you might want to keep track of every transaction a user makes in your ecommerce application (for accountability and safety reasons).

**tl;dr** use SQL because the data in a shoppingcart usecase is structured and consistent.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The general pros/cons of something like Cassandra vs postgres/mysql look like:

- Cassandra handles multi-DC HA much better.
- Cassandra handles high write volume much better.
- Cassandra allows you to reboot hosts without downtime because you'll have multiple replicas (and you wont have to worry about WAL replay or binlog replay or weird master-master replication problems, though some RDBMS addons make this easier for MySQL and Postgres than it used to be).
- Cassandra allows you to scale better (linear scaling with number of instances up to ~1200 or so instances)
- MySQL/Postgres allow you to build queries as your business requirements evolve by adding indices to existing tables; Cassandra expects you to know the queries in advance and do data modeling before you start writing data.
- MySQL/Postgres tends to be easier to use, and you'll find a ton of libraries/UIs/etc to help you get started
- MySQL/Postgres offer real transactions / MVCC - Casssandra has lightweight transactions limited to operations on a single key with much weaker isolation/atomicity guarantees.

Ultimately, though, unless you believe your shopping cart is going to handle thousands of concurrent users, it probably doesn't matter (as long as you use something with real data durability guarantees): use what you're most comfortable using. I'd use Cassandra because I know Cassandra very well, but if you're not great with Cassandra (or whatever), use what you know best.